# Which css rules are ignored when flexbox is active?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I configure flexbox to have a nice fallback? Say I have this:

```css
.parent{
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 width: 320px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.children{
 text-align: center;
 flex: 1;
 background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="children">1</div>
 <div class="children">2</div>
 <div class="children">3</div>
</div>
```

What rules am I allowed to add to have a nice fallback for older browsers and that they get completly ignored and don't disturb flexbox.

Notice I don't ask for a polifill or anything, I just want something that fallbacks to something similar. It would be nice to know exactly wich rules get ignored when flexbox is active. Obviously display is overwritten but, what about children's width? What about children's float? what about position: absolute? what about margins?

Comment: What browsers are you needing this to work on?

Comment: Not older than ie8, but even inside that range there are many that don't support is completly or at all.

Comment: Could you have a separate style sheet for older browsers. That styles it the old way with floats and widths. For example: `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->`

Comment: I could, but I want to understand what happens to other rules when flexbox is active

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers),

> Flex containers are not block containers, and so some properties that
>   were designed with the assumption of block layout don’t apply in the
>   context of flex layout. In particular:
>
> - the `column-*` properties in the Multi-column Layout module [[CSS3COL]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#biblio-css3col) have no effect on a flex container.
> - [`float`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-float) and [`clear`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) have no effect on a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), and do not take it out-of-flow. However, the [`float`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-float) property can
>     still affect box generation by influencing the [`display`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display)
>     property’s computed value.
> - [`vertical-align`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) has no effect on a flex item.
> - the [`::first-line`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-first-line) and `::first-letter` pseudo-elements do not apply to [flex containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container), and [flex containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) do not
>     contribute a first formatted line or first letter to their ancestors.

For your specific questions,

- Flex item width (assuming horizontal flow):

  > The flex item’s [**main size property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property) is either the [`width`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-width) or [`height`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-height)
  >   property, whichever is in the main dimension.

  This will be used as the [flex basis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis) if [`flex-basis`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis) is [`auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto):

  > When specified on a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), the `auto` keyword retrieves the
  >   value of the [main size property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property) as the used [`flex-basis`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis).

  Otherwise, it will be ignored.
- [Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

  > An absolutely-positioned child of a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) does not
  >   participate in flex layout. However, it does participate in the
  >   [reordering step](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-flex-order) (see [`order`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-order)), which has an effect in their painting
  >   order.
- [Flex Item Margins and Paddings](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins)

  > The margins of adjacent [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) do not collapse. Auto margins
  >   absorb extra space in the corresponding dimension and can be used for
  >   alignment and to push adjacent flex items apart; see [Aligning with
  >   `auto` margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins).
  >
  > Percentage margins and paddings on [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) are always
  >   resolved against their respective dimensions; unlike blocks, they do
  >   not always resolve against the inline dimension of their containing
  >   block.
  >
  > > Note: This behavior is [currently disputed](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Mar/0273.html), and might change in a
  > >     future version of this specification to match the behavior of blocks.

Comment: This is great! I don't completly understand what happens with margins when you have (for example) space-between. Do they get completly ignored or do they afect in some way?

Comment: @Vandervals `justify-content` specifies how to distribute flex items along each line. Visually it may seem like increasing the margin, but it's an independent phenomenon.

Comment: Then the visual margins will be increased but never dicreased, is that right?

Comment: @Vandervals Yes. First, the flex items are [arranged in lines](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-line-break). Then [the flexible lengths are resolved](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-flex). Finally, the [remaining space of each line is distributed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-main-align).