# float does not work in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to position text (foo link) in right of the footer element.

I need footer display to remain `flex`.

But when I set it to `flex`, `float:right` for span doesn't work anymore.

```html
<footer style="display: flex;">
     <span style="text-align: right;float: right;">
        <a>foo link</a>
     </span>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dhsgvxdx/

Comment: See [Which css rules are ignored when flexbox is active?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30500734/1529630)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `float` property is ignored in a flex container.

*From the flexbox specification:*

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> A flex container establishes a new *flex formatting context* for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout.
>
> For example, floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the
>   flex container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its
>   contents.
>
> `float` and `clear` do not create floating or clearance of flex item, and do not take it out-of-flow.

Instead, just use flex properties:

```css
footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <span>
       <a>foo link</a>
    </span>
</footer>
```

If you have more items in the footer, and need other alignment options, then here are two guides:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)
- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Comment: this didn't work but the margin-left: auto; from suggestion by @d-soderberg did

Answer (score 62):

It works if you add `margin-left: auto;` like I did here in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhsgvxdx/3/

```
<body>
    <footer style="display: flex;">
        <span style="text-align: right;float: right; margin-left: auto;">
            <a>foo link</a>
        </span>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I know its late reply but it will help others.. If you use `margin-left: auto` then no need to use `float: right` property....! In my case it worked without it..

Comment: @ShubhamJha Could you please explain the logic behind it.

Comment: The float:right and text-align:right are both unnecessary. The margin-left:auto does the trick. Great idea D.Soderberg

Answer (score 6):

If this footer is only to contain a right-aligned item, you can simply apply `justify-content: flex-end` to the flex container. This way, you do not have to add any styles to its children.

```
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXZaok)

Comment: yes. i try it. it works for some cases. but in my case, i have some element that need to be in left of the footer. and some in right.

Comment: In that case, use `justify-content: space-between` on the container - no need for floats or text-aligns.

Comment: hmmm. i test it. this is so good. by this way, elements automatically aligned.  tnx

Answer (score 2):

By default, flex items are laid out in the source order. However, the order property controls the order in which they appear in the flex container.

```
.item {
  order: 3; /* default is 0 */
}
```

Comment: I was struggling to break a flex component from the middle to a line below it's siblings while retaining the flex behavior of the siblings -- this solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you!