# How to float elements independently?

Tags: html, css, position, flexbox

I would like to position some elements at different distances from the left border of a parent `div`. Each element holds its own distance (in percentage of the width of the parent `div`).

Since `position` does not seem to be the right approach, I tried to do that by floating the element to the right

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#root {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
}
#one {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#two {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

My expectation was that the first element would be at 10% of the `div` width (so 5% of the page width, since the parent `div` is 50% width relative to the page) and the second one at 80%. This is not the case, the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) mention that

> Elements after a floating element will flow around it.

They also mention that `clear` can be used to avoid this but I did not manage to make it happen (that is to make it so that each float is recalculated from the left border of the parent `div`).

**Is this something which is possible?**

As a workaround I thought about calculating the float of the second element reltive to the first one, but that would horrendously(*) complicate my code so maybe there is a cleaner solution.

---

(*) For the case above that would be `80% - 20%` (the ones which are already floated) = `60%`. But even here the positionning is not correct (the `2` is too much to the right; there should be 20% blank, `1`, 40% blank, `2`, 20% blank - but the widths of the numbers themselves should be taken into account as well)

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#root {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
}
#one {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#two {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: float does't work with display flex

Comment: Be aware that floats are ignored in a flex container. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39194630/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B  (and GermanoPlebani) - ah? I was not aware of that. So why are the digits moved to the right in my first code snippet?

Comment: Because the margin rules you set still apply.

Comment: @Michael_B: ah ok, thank you , now this is clear. I will rephrase my question to make it clear that I am looking to recalculate the margins from the left side of the parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can position element the way you want with `position: absolute` on the child elements. But keep in mind that the child elements don't control the height of the outer element.

```
#root {
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  width: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 20px;
}
#one {
  border: solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20%;
}
#two {
  border: solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 60%;
}

<div id="root">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uu0oftyr/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: [the percentage value for your distance];
```

Erase the flex settings from the container and add `overflow: hidden` to make sure the floats are considered part of the containers height.

Here is an example:

```css
#root {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#one {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#two {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

P.S.: You could do something similar with all *right* settings:

```
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  margin-right: [...];
```