# Align a sub menu for a displayed flex parent menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a submenu underneath a menu that has the property `display: flex`, and the list items have the property `flex-grow: 1`

I would like to align the submenu so that the links are aligned with the parent like so:

[image]

This is working because I gave the submenu the property `left: 19px`. This works but the problem is that since the menu and its items are displayed flex, when the browser shrinks the width of the list item shrinks with it, so the submenu does not get aligned. Below is a screenshot when the browser shrunk 200px:

[image]

Is there a css class or anything I can do to have the submenu links align with the parent links on browser shrink? I could technically make a ton of media queries and change the `left:` but I thought I would ask if anyone has a better solution.

Here is my code. I stripped out alot but left the code that seemed necessary for this question.

```css
#menu-main-menu {
  display: flex;
}
#menu-main-menu li {
  float: left;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#menu-main-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40.5px 0;
}
#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/services/" class="">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="">Child Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">Child Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">Child Page</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try removing all ul li default paddings and margins, `ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe in your question cannot be reproduced with the code you provided. However, based on your explanation, here are two things to consider:

- [An initial value of a flex container is `flex-shrink: 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276). This means that flex items are allowed to shrink in order to fit inside the container (preventing overflow). In order to disable shrinking, add `flex-shrink: 0` to flex items.
- [Floats are ignored in a flex container.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39194630/3597276)

Also, as general guidance, consider these rules, as well:

- [Absolutely positioned flex items do not participate in flex layout.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991536/3597276)
- [A flex item cannot, by default, shrink past the size of its content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276).

One of the factors above may be causing, or at least contributing, to your problem.