# Pin element to the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

Looking for the View Button to be locked to the bottom, using `position:absolute;` would cause the price to merge into the View Button.

https://jsfiddle.net/kieranbs96/pj8emf0a/

```
a.view-button {
 float: left;
 padding: 7px 30px;
 background: #e35f00;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.offer, .recommendation {
 float: left;
 flex: 1 0 32%;
 margin: 0 0.3%;
 width: 32%;
 position: relative;
}
```

Any questions please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `div.offer` box a (nested) flex container in column-direction. Then pin the view button to the bottom with a flex `auto` margin.

```
.offer, .recommendation {
    float: left;
    flex: 1 0 32%;
    margin: 0 0.3%;
    width: 32%;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;          /* new */
    flex-direction: column; /* new */
}

a.view-button {
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 30px;
    background: #e35f00;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    margin-top: auto;       /* new */
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pj8emf0a/2/)

A few more things to keep in mind:

- [Flex layout exists only between parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276).
- [Floats are ignored in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39194800/3597276).
- [Avoid using percentages for margin and padding in a flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783414/3597276).