# Safari 8 Flexbox float and center

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

Whatever I do, I can't seem to get the columns that float left and right to center and align to the middle of it's container. Is there a way with Flexbox only to just have a left and right column, but still align them in the middle? It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari 8.

https://jsfiddle.net/vhem8scs/68/

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.column:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column div {
  float: left;
}
.column div:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

**Update**

I added the following line to the container.

```
justify-content: space-between
```

While it aligns to the center/middle of the container, the floats do not work now.

Comment: Try `justify-content: space-between` in your `.container` class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @lux that's correct, and thanks I had to update the title though because I am only experiencing the alignment issue in Safari 8. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: [Floats are ignored in a flex container.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39194630/3597276)

Comment: [Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is rather difficult to visualize what you're trying to accomplish with your styles, but here's my preliminary analysis of the issue.

Once you declare an element to be a flex container, all the children will follow flexbox rules. Float styles will essentially be ignored. As a result, what you might want to try doing is making use of the `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` properties on the children to ensure columns sit in the proper position.

If you goal is to simply put space in between the columns, utilize the `justify-content` property with either `space-around` or `space-between` on the parent flex element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I am just trying to have two columns with one that floats to the left, and one to the right, but align them in the middle/center of the container.