# Why does display flex cause child img to shrink when text flows to second line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, materialize

While using [Material design responsive image](http://materializecss.com/media-css.html) I noticed even if I give fixed width to `col`, its size decreases as the container width decreases. I have breaked it down to a reproducible snippet:

```css
.row {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  float: left;
}

.pic {
  width: 80px;
}

.pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col pic">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e1/38/a1/e138a174c33a48931521dcc5639d4a03--happy-pictures-smiley-faces.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col"> Resize the window to decrease it's width. When the text starts wrapping to second line the image starts shrinking</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fbcggd8/

To see the problem try resizing the jsfiddle output section(right bottom). You'll notice the image which should be fixed 80px width decreases in size as the text wraps to second line. Why does this happen?

Comment: Keep in mind that your `float: left` on `.col` is doing nothing. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39194630/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I think `float: left` on `col` acts as a fallback for older browsers in Material design.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to fix it, probably the simplest is just to add `flex-shrink: 0` to `.pic` to keep it from shrinking. By default, it will shrink (initial value is `flex-shrink: 1`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

You could also remove the `width` and use `flex: 0 0 80px` which is short hand for `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 80px`

```css
.row {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.pic {
  width: 80px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col pic">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e1/38/a1/e138a174c33a48931521dcc5639d4a03--happy-pictures-smiley-faces.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col"> Resize the window to decrease it's width. When the text starts wrapping to second line the image starts shrinking</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This pretty much covers it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width

Answer (score 2):

Just add `flex:1 0 80px;` to get it.
by default `flex-shrink` is `1` so if you assign it to `0` to get it.

```
.pic {
  /* width: 80px; */
  /* Remove it */
  flex: 1 0 80px;
}
```

```css
.row {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  float: left;
}

.pic {
  /* width: 80px; */
  /* Remove it */
  flex: 1 0 80px;
}

.pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col pic">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e1/38/a1/e138a174c33a48931521dcc5639d4a03--happy-pictures-smiley-faces.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col"> Resize the window to decrease it's width. When the text starts wrapping to second line the image starts shrinking</div>
</div>
```

**[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fbcggd8/2/)**