# Alignment of fields not working as expected

Tags: html, css, angular, angular7

I am trying to align the field in the Angular html page and it is not working as expected. The html file is like below

```
<div id="report-prj-search">
  <div class="dx-fieldset flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row-container">
      <div class="dx-field flex-row">
        <div class="dx-field-label">ShipTo Account</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value">
          <dx-select-box [dataSource]="ShipmentList" displayExpr="customer_shipto_name"  (onValueChanged)="onValueChanged($event)" ></dx-select-box>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dx-field flex-row">
        <div class="dx-field-label">Purchase Order</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value">
          <dx-select-box [dataSource]="purchaseOrder" displayExpr="customer_purchase_order" ></dx-select-box>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dx-field">
      <dx-button (onClick)="click($event)">Filter</dx-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And .scss is like

```
.dx-fieldset.flex-column  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-row-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.dx-field.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
.dx-select-box {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 2vw;
  float: left;
}
```

But the fileds are not aligned properly and I am not able to resize the selectbox size/ lable size also the alignment is little off like below

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `float` within a `flex` container element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194630/float-does-not-work-in-a-flex-container

Comment: @trx Remove the float and use `align-items: flex-end` as @Jojofoulk told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The reason

So I figured out the issue is actually not because of your CSS (although using `float` in a flex container is still wrong, so you can just remove it) but it's purely due to the theming used by your library.

From the names of your component elements, I assume you areusing Devextreme, and from looking at your screenshot, it looks like you are using one of their (fairly recent) material themes, *blue light* it looks like.

The problem is what they do in the CSS with `<dx-field>` elements
It turns out that the CSS from material themes contains:

```
.dx-field {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
```

which is fine and gives some space for fields that are placed under it BUT also contains:

```
.dx-field:last-of-type {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Because of this, the last `<dx-field>` will have its margin overridden to 0. This isn't wrong if the fields are placed in a column order (which is probably what they assume would always be the case), but in your case, you're in a flex container with a row direction, so losing that margin looks weird.

#### The Fix

To fix it you can change the last element css, something like:

```
dx-field:last-of-type {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can just remove the bottom margin to all elements:

```
dx-field {
    margin: 0;
}
```

*Fun fact, the default Devextreme themes don't have this issue, so it's probably some weird Material Theme Guidelines*