# Why is float not moving my log in and signup to the right side of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my log in and sign-up buttons to move to the right side of the screen and can't seem to get them there. I first tried adjusting their left-padding to move them and while it gets them there when full screen as soon as the screen is adjusted their size becomes inconsistent. I saw some examples of how to get them there by using float: right but when I do that it doesn't move them the entire way.

Here is my html: https://pastebin.com/7kAS3Ln5

and my CSS: https://pastebin.com/ffDLJd7j

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.topnav{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh / 10);
    background-color: #2B78E4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
}
.topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
.helmet-logo {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;


}
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;


}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-style: inherit;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.nav-btn{
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
#login-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
#signUp-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#login-btn, #signUp-btn {
    float: right;
}

#teams-btn{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <img src="fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class = "helmet-logo">
        <div id ="teams-btn">

           <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="#Teams">Teams</a></button>

        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Seasons
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2022">2022</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2021">2021</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2020">2020</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id ="login-btn">
            <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="#Login">Log In</a></button>
        </div>

        <div id ="signUp-btn">
        <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href ="#signup">Sign Up</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: why space between class and value? `class = "nav-btn"`

Comment: idk i'm new to web dev so probably a habit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194630/float-does-not-work-in-a-flex-container

float will not work within a flex container. your buttons are inside the flex container as it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `float`. Those items have a flex container so you can simply use `margin-left` and it will give you the expected result. Here are the changes:

```
#login-btn{
    margin-left: auto;
}

#signUp-btn{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.topnav{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh / 10);
    background-color: #2B78E4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
}
.topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
.helmet-logo {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;


}
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;


}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-style: inherit;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.nav-btn{
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
#login-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
#signUp-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#login-btn, #signUp-btn {
    /* float: right; */
}

#login-btn{
    margin-left: auto;
}

#signUp-btn{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#teams-btn{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <img src="fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class = "helmet-logo">
        <div id ="teams-btn">

           <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="#Teams">Teams</a></button>

        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Seasons
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2022">2022</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2021">2021</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2020">2020</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id ="login-btn">
            <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="#Login">Log In</a></button>
        </div>

        <div id ="signUp-btn">
        <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href ="#signup">Sign Up</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```